# Wordpress allow access only one custom post type "xyz" to custom user role but need to hide all admin panels

Tags: custom-post-types, users, capabilities

I have Wordpress website and has some user roles and I want to show related admin panels for their roles.

I have checked few user role plugins but not found any solution.

basically, We need to set up a user role "manager", who can only access few menus at backend like custom post type "manager_deals" but need to hide all panels in admin.

Comment: how do you create the post type ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a free WordPress plugin **Adminimize** to provide access of custom post type or admin menu to the specific type of user role.

Adminimize: https://wordpress.org/plugins/adminimize/

Hope this helps...Let me know if you need any additional help.