# How do I hide "Pages", "Media", "Comments"....for editor role?

Tags: menus

How do I hide "Pages", "Media", "Comments"....for editor role?

[image]

Comment: You can use Adminimize free WordPress plugin to manage visibility of admin menu links.
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/304544/wordpress-allow-access-only-one-custom-post-type-xyz-to-custom-user-role-but-n/304548#304548

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
/** remove editor dashboard menu
*/ define( 'DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT', true);
 
function remove_menus(){

  remove_menu_page( 'index.php' );                  //Dashboard  
  remove_menu_page( 'jetpack' );                    //Jetpack*   //
  remove_menu_page( 'edit.php' );                   //Posts  
  remove_menu_page( 'upload.php' );                 //Media  
  remove_menu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=page' );    //Pages  
  remove_menu_page( 'edit-comments.php' );          //Comments  
  remove_menu_page( 'themes.php' );                 //Appearance  
  remove_menu_page( 'plugins.php' );                //Plugins  
  remove_menu_page( 'users.php' );                  //Users  
  remove_menu_page( 'tools.php' );                  //Tools  
  remove_menu_page( 'options-general.php' );        //Settings
  remove_menu_page( 'wpcf7' );        //contact form

}

if ( current_user_can( 'editor' ) ){
    add_action( 'admin_menu', 'remove_menus' );
}
```

I found the solution,
add these in theme function.php